# Remove all blank lines from *.txt files in the directory and subfolders in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Searching, trying and crying I developed a code:

```
For /R %%G IN (*.txt) do for /f "delims=" %%a in ('more +1 %%G ^| find /v ""') do (set line=%%~a echo !line!) > new\%%G
```

Do someone know why does it loop forever?

What it is expected to do, is to remove blank lines in every *.txt file it founds in all subdirectories and put the new file with the same name in "new" folder. I can provide all "new" folders needed manually.

Comment: Are you aware, that `more +1` removes the first line of every file? (might be your intention)

Comment: i'm totally new to this topic. I didn't know it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this would cause it to loop forever, but you are writing to a NEW folder that is in the same hierarchy that you are reading from. So it will process files that you just wrote. You will need a filter to prevent that.

Also, I think your output file name needs `%%~nxG` to get just the file name and extension, without the path.

There is a much simpler way to strip out blank lines. `findstr . file` will strip out empty lines. `findstr /rc:"[^ ]` will strip out empty lines and lines that contain only spaces.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "outFolder=new"
for %%F in ("%outfolder%\.") for /r %%G in (*.txt) do if "%%~dpG" neq "%%~fF\" findstr /rc:"[^ ]" "%%G" >"%%~fF\%%~nxG"
```

But the simplest thing to do is just make sure your output folder is distinct from your source hierarchy

```
for /r %%G in (*.txt) do findstr /rc:"[^ ]" "%%G" >"\distinctPath\%%~nxG"
```

**UPDATE**

One thing that could cause your script to hang is that piped MORE will hang if the file has more than 64k lines. But I don't understand why you are using MORE in the first place.